# Vuex getter not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the below getter:

```js
    withEarmarks: state => {
        var count = 0;
        for (let l of state.laptops) {
            if (l.earmarks.length > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
      return count;
    }
```

And in a component, this computed property derived from that getter:

```js
        withEarmarks() { return this.$store.getters.withEarmarks; },
```

The value returned is correct, until I change an element within the laptops array, and then the getter doesn't update.

Comment: How are you making changes in the `laptops` array, can you include that code.

Comment: @saurabh I have tried both these ways: `state.laptops[index] = laptop;` and `state.laptops[index] = Object.assign({}, laptop);`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In your case `state.laptops.earmarks` is an array, and you are manipulating it by its array index `state.laptops[index]`. Vue is unable to react to mutations on state arrays (by index). The documentation provides 2 workarounds for this:

```js
// 1. use purpose built vue method:
Vue.set(state.laptops, index, laptop)
  
// 2. splice the value in at an index:
state.laptops.splice(index, 1, laptop)
```

*Although it is documented, I'm thinking a giant neon glowing sign on that page that says "You will waste hours of productivity if you don't know this" would be a nice addition*.

You can read more about this "caveat" here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: `state.laptops = [laptop, ...state.laptops]`

Comment: Big fan of this actually. `[laptop, ...state.laptops]` is basically an `unshift` and [...state.laptops, laptop] is a `push`.

Comment: I had a similar question in regards to an Object used as a map and changing the properties. Doing a `state.map = _.clone(state.map)` did the trick for me.

Comment: This is a nice summary of this issue:
> You will waste hours of productivity if you don't know this"

Comment: "giant neon glowing sign" lol so true. Thx for SO existence.

Comment: I'd like to join the "hours of wasted productivity club"

Comment: literal hours. how is this not more prominent in the docs.

Comment: The "caveat" link is outdated and is now: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: Posted link is outdated, this explains more about the Vue.set method and its reactivity https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Reactivity issue and Vue caveat, there could be another reason, You've introduced the local variable `counter` in computed function, You can try using `reduce` function as given.

```js
withEarmarks: state => {
    return state.laptops.reduce((acc, item) => {
        if(item.earmarks.length > 0){
            acc++;
        }
        return acc;
    }, 0);
}
```

consider the @jpschroeder's answer in addition of this answer.

Comment: A common error of this is also the states variable not being initialized on load.  it happens to me often.

i.e: state.laptops MUST exist on the state when Vuex is loaded.