# What is the best practice for reactive setter for an object in array in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex object with array of languages that has objects with guid, name and level.

How can I write method so that it will make it reactive. I got to the point where I have input field with value="language.name" and **I want to write method for @input but I don't know what best practice for it.**

I have Vuex store:

```
const state = () => ({
  ...
  obj: {
    skills: [],
    languages: []
  },
  ...
})
```

An example the use in template in `v-for="(language, index) in obj.languages"`:

```
v-text-field(
  :value="language.name"
  @input="setLanguage"
)
```

And code after reading in depth about [getters](https://codeburst.io/vuex-getters-are-great-but-dont-overuse-them-9c946689b414), [setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767191/vuex-update-an-entire-array), [modern Javascript limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860592/vuex-getter-not-updating) for Vue so it can't track changes of an array in state therefore it is required to use workaround as Vue.set() built-in method and use of [TodoMVC example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/todomvc) on vuex github that I came up with:

```
setLanguage: (e) => {
  function f({language, guid = language.guid, name = language.name, level = language.level}){
    Vue.set(this.$store.state.obj.languages, this.$store.state.obj.languages.findIndex((it) => it.guid === guid), {guid, name, level})
  }
  const name = e.target.value.trim()
  const language = this
  f({language, name})
}
```

It doesn't seems to be right. And I feel I don't understand the concept.

**Can you show what is the best practice to make reactive objects of an array in state of vuex?**

Answer (score 0):

With vuex, you want to be using actions and mutations.

```
setLanguage: (e, index) => {
  let name = e.target.value.trim()
  this.$store.dispatch('setLanguage', {name, index}) //dispatches a vuex action
}
```

Then define an action:

```
setLanguage({ commit }, payload) {
  commit('setLanguage', payload) //commits a vuex mutation
}
```

And finally a mutation:

```
setLanguage(state, payload) {
  state.languages[payload.index].name = payload.name
}
```

see the vuex documentation on this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html